# $ \int_0^{\infty} \, e^{-a^2x^2} \operatorname{erf}(bx) \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, gaussian-integral, error-function

I'd like to know the proof of this formula

$$ \int_0^{\infty}  \, e^{-a^2x^2} \operatorname{erf}(bx) \, dx=\frac{1}{a\sqrt{\pi}}\arctan{\frac{b}{a}}$$

where $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ is the error function
$\operatorname{erf}(x):=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{x}  e^{-y^2} \, dy$.

Comment: Did you try changing the order of integration.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried integration by parts

Comment: I have to derive with respect b and then integrate! I thought that it was more difficult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: transform the double integral into polar coordinates:
$$\frac{2b} {\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2x^2}dx\int_0^x e^{-b^2y^2}dy\\
=\frac{2b} {\sqrt\pi}\int_0^{\pi/4} d\phi\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2 (a^2\cos^2\phi+b^2\sin^2\phi)}rdr
=\frac b {\sqrt\pi}\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac {d\phi}{a^2\cos^2\phi+b^2\sin^2\phi}
$$
and use $t=\tan \phi $ substitution.

Answer (score 4):

Your idea to use Feynman trick was good
$$I(b)=\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2 x^2} \text{erf}(b x)\,dx$$ $$I'(b)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_0^\infty x e^{- \left(a^2+b^2\right)x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_0^\infty  e^{- \left(a^2+b^2\right)t}\,dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi } \left(a^2+b^2\right)}$$
$$I(b)=\frac{1}{\sqrt \pi }\int \frac{db}{ \left(a^2+b^2\right)}=\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } a}+C$$ and, since $I(0)=0$, then the result.